# when does the memory, pointed by (char *) as function parameter gets deleted?

Tags: c++, char, parameter-passing

code 1 :

```
void foo(char * text) {}

foo("Test");
```

as far as i understand, this will happen :

- memory is allocated for "Test"
- pointer is created and its value is copyed to (char * text pointer), so (char * text) points to the place in memory, where "Test" is (better to say, on the first char of "Test")
- after the function is done, it destroys the pointer(char * text), pointing to the beginning of "Test", doesnt create this a memory leak?
- **and the question is, when does the "Test" gets deleted, when the function destroys only the pointer**

isn't it better to do smth. like that? :

```
char * _text = "Test";
foo(_text);
delete[] _text;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of string literals as being part of the code. They aren't dynamically allocated, they have so-called "static storage duration", which means they exist for the duration of the program, and they don't need to be freed (indeed, must not be freed).

It is always wrong to `delete[]` something that wasn't created with `new[]`, so your second code snippet has undefined behavior.

Comment: when i do //
char * _text = "Test";
foo(_text);// will the "Test" also be create in static storage? //so i don't need to call delete? wouldn't it be better to use const char * _text  = "Test"? why can i pass it as a char *, when i fact its a const char *

Comment: @Peter: there is a deprecated conversion from string literal to non-const `char*`. It's there to support legacy C code from before `const` was invented (in chess notation, one would write (?!) here). Using it *doesn't* make it OK to modify the data that it points to, it just has the same effect as removing const from a pointer with a `const_cast`. If you want something you can modify, you could write `char text[] = "Test";` - this puts an array on the stack and copies the string literal into that array, so you can modify the copy. Like any other automatic variable, its lifetime is its scope.

Answer (score 2):

"Test" is a string literal, which has a static storage duration. It will not be deleted until the program works. And you should not delete it by yourself.

Comment: so its smth. like leaked memory? when i do smth like  : foo("Test"); foo("Test"); will this create 2 constants?

Comment: It is not a leaked memory. It will be deleted automatically when the program will exit (just after returning from the function `main`).

Comment: Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation defined. So you shouldn't count on that `foo("Test"); foo("Test");` will call `foo` with the same pointer value.

Comment: so the best solution is to use #define MYTEXT "Test" and call foo(MYTEXT); foo(MYTEXT);

Comment: I wouldn't use `define`. Use `const char* MYTEXT = "Test";` instead.

Comment: @Peter Lapisu: no, for 2 reasons. 
First - the `MYTEXT` is resolved at preprocessing time by just doing string substitution of MYTEXT with "Test". So when you compiler gets the program it is just the same as `foo("Test"); foo("Test");`. 
Second - why do you care? You don't need to allocate and free it, you should not modify it, so it's ok as it is, isn't it?
What you could do is `static const char* MYTEXT="Test";`, but the compiler most probably does it implicitly when you just write "Test".

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't get deleted.

That string is allocated in data segment and the call to `foo("Test")` just pushes on the stack the pointer to that string, without "copying" it as you are saying.

It is not leaked memory because the string is part of the final binary file and it will always be there, in a section of the binary that is just for that kind of things (constants and so on).

It happens that the string itself (the bytes for "Test") are placed in data segment in a read-only section while the pointer (eg `char *_test = "Test"`) is instead stored in a read-write section (stack or heap, it depends how the pointer is initialized and used). You are allowed to modify the pointer but that won't delete the string from the data segment.

Answer (score 0):

Hard coded values in C are actually compiled into the binary and as such are not allocated. More correctly they appear in the "data" section of the executable and live as long as the program does.

Also, pointers are not "destroyed". Remember that pointers are just addresses to memory that may be anywhere (stack/heap) but pointers a not objects.

Comment: Pointers are objects in the only sense that C++ defines "object", although that definition doesn't accord with the OOP definition of "object". It's kind of moot whether they're destroyed, since their destruction has no effect, but they have a lifetime like any other object.

Comment: @Steve: A pointer such as `&var` is not an object. A pointer *variable*, however, is.

Comment: @FredOverflow: good nitpicking, yes, perhaps I should have said "pointers *can be* objects" etc. `&var` of course is an rvalue. Likewise given `int i;`, `i` is an object but `-i` is an rvalue.